# backup database of mysql code not working

Tags: java, mysql

I used following JAVA code for write a backup file of MySQL database, but when I run this code there is no backup created. What is the problem with this ?

```
public void writeBackup(String date, int x) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process runtimeProcess = runTime.exec("mysqldump Healthplus -h localhost -u root -pmysql -r D:/HealthplusBackups/Healthplus" + date + ".sql");
}
```

Comment: You can use the `getErrorStream()` to read the process' error stream to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the command should be `"mysqldump -h localhost -u root -pmysql -r Healthplus > D:/HealthplusBackups/Healthplus" + date + ".sql"`

Answer (score 0):

The mysqldump command should read

```
mysqldump -f --opt --user=root --password=mysql --databases Healthplus > D:/HealthplusBackups/Healthplus" + date + ".sql
```

However it assumes you have access to the folder on the D drive, and it will also do a force dump so if there are any errors it should continue.